# Numerous instances of VBCSCompiler.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I just recently downloaded and installed Visual Studio Professional 2015 (14.0.23107.0). The first time I opened up our solution (28 projects) and performed a Build -> Rebuild Solution, my development machine came to an absolute crawl. The CPU was maxed out at 100% and the build never completed - even after > 10 minutes.

I opened up Windows Task Manager and noticed: > 10 VBCSCompiler.exe tasks running. When combined, these tasks sent the CPU > 90%.

Any idea why there are so many of these tasks running? Any way to stop this from happening?

This is the closest thing I can find to someone else experiencing the same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2790

**Update (8/7)**

-Hans Passant, great thought. My manager provided me with this release (14.0.23107.0). Is this the correct version for the "official release"?? I did not knowingly install any of the per-release versions of Visual Studio 2015. I don't think there are any beta bits lying around.

-Kyle Trauberman, I'm not that familiar with environment variables in the context of Visual Studio; however, I naively ran `set DisableRosyln=true` in a VS (and MSBuild) Command Prompt Window. This did not seem to have any impact. VBCSCompiler.exe showed right back up even after restarting VS2015.

I repaired my VS2015 install and performed a reboot. This did not help.

**Update Part 2 (8/7)**
-Hans Passant, very impressive write up!! Although, the problem didn't happen this time around, I took a look at the things you described:

As far as the modules loaded with the VBCSCompiler.exe, here's what I have:

[image]

It's interesting that our .NET core assemblies are at different versions. You're at 4.06.79 while, I'm at 4.06.81.

My "client side dlls" (located at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll) are at the same version and time stamp as yours:
[image]

Oddly enough, when I look at the code in ILSpy, I see something slightly different - optimization perhaps?

```
    private static NamedPipeClientStream TryAllProcesses(string pipeName, int timeoutMs, CancellationToken cancellationToken, out string newPipeName)
{
    string str = pipeName;
    int num = 1;
    while (File.Exists(string.Format("\\\\.\\pipe\\{0}", pipeName)))
    {
        NamedPipeClientStream result;
        if ((result = BuildClient.TryConnectToProcess(pipeName, timeoutMs, cancellationToken)) != null)
        {
            newPipeName = pipeName;
            return result;
        }
        pipeName = str + "." + num.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        num++;
    }
    newPipeName = pipeName;
    return null;
}
```

**Let me get back with you on the specific pipname argument passed to the instances of VBCSCompiler.exe. I will have to wait until it happens again.

Comment: may want to change the tag from visual-studio to specifically visual-studio-2015, as it's specific to this version of it.  Might get a little bit more attention from people more familiar with the matter that way.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: 22 VBCSCompiler.exe processes running at the same time using 100% CPU (16 cores) and 300MB each of RAM. I noticed this happens when I change mercurial branch of my project and let VS reload the solution and then build. At this point I have to kill the process manually or logout.

Comment: @gigi Same happens to me sometimes. Do you use ReSharper?

Comment: @splattne Yes I do. Latest version available. Do you think it might be the cause?

Comment: @splattne It's just a guest, but at this point it's at least a possibility. I'll ping Jetbrains about it.

Comment: I use resharper as well. That's an interesting observation... Thanks for the input.

Comment: FYI: Similar issue is discussed here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2790

Comment: This could be the solution (fix in Roslyn)  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5466 (mentioned in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2790#event-421123250 )

Comment: Adding that I have also experienced this issue, but I do NOT use Resharper

Comment: I am having this issue, with VS2105, 14.0.25425.01 Update 3. There is no Resharper. It launches instances under my workstation user name, and the App Pool name. If I make "significant" changes to the project, e.g., add a control to a page (e.g., a literal), it seems to launch another compiler or two. This also happens if there is a compile error giving the yellow screen. This also happens if I edit/rebuild/refresh too fast (within a minute... really? have to slow down that much?) The solution to UseSharedCompilation false seems to launch only one, once I did it on all projects in the solution.

Comment: I have the same issue.  The process locks up some DLLs when I edit Razor syntax while my MVC web application is running.  The only way to have a successful run after that is to use the task manager to stop the processes the delete everything in my bin.  When I only make edits when my project is not running then I don't have problems.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmm, there is no obvious repro scenario and nobody else complains about this. Your solution is not unusual at all.  Pegging the cpu to 100% and getting the VBCSCompiler process to swallow ~1.5 GB isn't very hard on a large project but it is squeaky clean when I look at mine.

First possible failure scenario that you have some uninstalled beta bits lying around, a very common problem.  Use the debugger to have a look-see.  Use Debug > Attach to Process and pick one of the running instances.  Then Debug > Break All and Debug > View > Modules.  Pay attention to the version numbers and timestamps, they ought to look like this:

[image]

Note that intentionally hid some columns to keep it readable.  Time stamps are CST timezone.

---

That's the server side.  The client side that had the bug you discovered is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll.  Have a look at its properties, mine is 85,192 bytes and created on Sunday, ‎June ‎21, ‎2015, ‏‎7:06:54 PM, File version number 1.0.0.50618.  You can look at the file with a decompiler like Reflector or ILSpy, navigate to BuildClient.TryAllProcesses().  The relevant line with the bug fix is:

```
for (int i = 1; File.Exists(string.Format(@"\\.\pipe\{0}", pipeName)); i++)
```

The buggy version was missing `\\.\pipe\`.

---

Note how error checking is very inadequate in the above snippet, File.Exists() returns *false* for many reasons.  Also the basic reason the bug wasn't discovered earlier. That enables several possible failure modes, the kind enabled if your machine is infected by the typical shrinked-wrapped malware that programmers voluntarily install.  The server and client code connect through each other through a named pipe with a special name.  Something you can see in Task Manager, Processes tab.  Use View > Select Columns (Win8 and up: right-click a column header) and tick the "Command line" option:
[image]

Note the `-pipename` argument.  If the File.Exists() call returns *false* then MSBuild will start VBCSCompiler.exe again.  If you see all these instances running with the same -pipename argument then you have software running on your machine that is interfering with normal named pipe usage.  First thing you'd consider then is to look for a less aggressive anti-malware solution.  You can write a little test program that uses the System.IO.Pipes namespace to get a better exception message.

Comment: I had the same issue. My VBCSCompiler.exe came from the bin folder of my web app. Needed to update a package.

Answer (score 21):

> Any idea why there are so many of these tasks running?

Roslyn uses a shared compiler process that keeps your compiled code in memory for reuse in subsequent compiles. So the second compile will be quicker, but as you've seen there's a memory overhead.

> Any way to stop this from happening?

Yes. From [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/releases/VS2015/src/Compilers/Core/MSBuildTask/ManagedCompiler.cs#L263-L273) there's a property of the compile task in msbuild that turns off the shared compiler, and it's set to true by [default](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/releases/VS2015/src/Compilers/Core/MSBuildTask/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets#L62-L64).

So in each project you'll have to add this property to the project file. Or in Visual Studio 2015 there's now shared projects, where you could add this property to the shared project and then include that shared project in all the other projects that need this setting.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseSharedCompilation>false</UseSharedCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This has been happening to me too.VS2015 free edition doing MVC5 development.  I've had 14+ instances of VCCSCompiler showing up, turning my laptop into a furnace.  Your suggestion of `UseSharedCompilation` has helped, I'm still getting more than one instance show up from time to time, but not more than 5.

Comment: I am having this issue, with VS2105, 14.0.25425.01 Update 3. See my comment above in the question. This answer worked - seems to launch only one, once I did it on all projects in the solution.

Comment: This worked for me too, I had around 10 instances using all my cpu, once i made this change it went down to a manageable resource amount, thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

As of November 22, 2015 this issue was still happening to me in the Visual Studio 2015 community edition.  My laptop was starting to double as a space heater with all of the instances of VBCSCompiler running full throttle.

The only fix that worked for me was to locate the file VBCSCompiler.exe in the /bin/roslyn directory of the web application and **change security permissions** on it.

You need to **deny** read & execute permission for the AppPool that your web app is running under.

[image]

Comment: @jerhewet glad it helped save someone cpu cycles

Comment: This is no solution. Immediately after doing this app starts crashing with: Access to the path 'D:\....\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' is denied.

Comment: It's important that you use the name of your application pool.

Answer (score 2):

According to Slaks, you can disable roslyn (which is what the VBCSCompiler.exe appears to be) by setting the `DisableRoslyn` environment variable to `true`.

See http://blog.slaks.net/2014-05-21/exploring-roslyn-part-2-inside-end-user-preview/ for more information.

Note, the link above is for the preview, but I can't imagine that it would have changed much between then and now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change "keep alive" option for VBCSCompiler, to close it just after execution...
You need to modify "VBCSCompiler.exe.config" file ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\VBCSCompiler.exe.config") and set needed value in seconds (by default it's 600).

Comment: 1 minute after doing this same problem appears.

Comment: Changing this setting does not solve anything. The rogue processes do not consider themselves idle, so they never begin counting down the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this issue with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Update 1.
The issue was solved by upgrading to Update 2.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the identity to 'NetworkService' in the Application pool advanced settings sorted out the problem for me.